# How to use php_codesniffer for upgrading and compatibility check (PHP 5.2 against PHP 5.4)

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP project with PHP version 5.2. Now I want to upgrade my project to use PHP version 5.4. I installed php 5.4 and deployed my project to use PHP 5.4. Now is there any tool to check for syntax errors OR coding standards OR compatibility check against PHP 5.4?

How about if I use php_codesniffer for the same? Can I use php_codesniffer to check for type compatibility if I upgrade from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.4?

Comment: Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is certainly possible. Install the PHPCompatibility standard for PHP_CodeSniffer from Wim Godden:

https://github.com/wimg/PHPCompatibility

Read more about it here:

http://techblog.wimgodden.be/2012/03/04/php-5-4-compatibility-checks-using-php_codesniffer/

It's really is as easy as installing PHP_CodeSniffer and the PHPCompatibility standard then running it against your code base. Hope that helps.